# ofstreamのopen失敗時の例外メッセージは、なぜbasic_ios::clearになるのでしょうか？

Tags: c++, c++11

以下のようなコードでファイルオープンエラーを検出したいです。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream fout;

    try
    {
        fout.exceptions(std::ofstream::failbit);
        fout.open("/tmp/hoge/hoge.txt");
    }
    catch(const std::ofstream::failure e)
    {
        std::cout << "msg=" << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

実行結果は、

```
$ ./a.out
msg=basic_ios::clear
```

となります。

```
msg=basic_ios::failbit
```

のような結果を期待しているのですが、なぜbasic_ios::clearになるのでしょうか？
それとも私の実装方法に間違いがあるのでしょうか？

Comment: [C++/CLI](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI)は無関係な印象ですが、理解していますか？

Comment: すみません。C++/CLIタグは削除しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ios_base::failure::what()`が[どんなメッセージを返すのか](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/ios/basic_ios/exceptions.html)は決まっていないので、標準ライブラリの実装依存です。

[gcc 7.2.0の場合](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FDtRzu3FoITc8jvN)：

> msg=basic_ios::clear: iostream error

[clang 5.0.0の場合](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xsR8XX1CQnZAJPOp)：

> msg=ios_base::clear: unspecified iostream_category error

Visual C++ 2017の場合：

> msg=ios_base::failbit set: iostream stream error

Comment: リンクのリファレンスを参照させていただきました。exception()の仕様からすると「basic_ios::clear」は納得できそうなので、解決としたいと思います。また、wondboxでの確認もありがとうございました。